# a tag is not clickable inside div

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to implement a flipping card, and place two tags at the back of the card. What happens is that first a tag inside div.sm is not clickable and second is working fine. Below are JSX and CSS/SCSS.

It also starts happening when I add transform: translate(-50%,-50%) to sm class. Thank you for the help

```css
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.col-1 {
    margin-left: -30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.7s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-back-content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.sm {
    background-color: $off-white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div className="flip-card col-1">
    <div className="flip-card-inner">
        <div className="flip-card-front">
            <img src="#"/>
        </div>
        <div className="flip-card-back">
            <div className="flip-card-back-content">
                <h5>Text</h5>
                <span>Some text</span>
                <div className="sm">
                    <a
                        href="#"
                    >
                        <FaGlobeAmericas />
                    </a>
                    <a
                        href="#"
                    >
                        <FaGlobeAmericas />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Since this is a styling issue, can you edit the question to include the HTML and CSS as a [runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to demonstrate?

Comment: `<FaGlobeAmericas />` is by no means a valid HTML tag.

Comment: @connexo well it's a `jsx` maybe that he imported

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have made some tags instead of text in the a tags.
FaGlobeAmericas in not a valid html tag.
Test if this html code works.

```
<div className="flip-card col-1">
    <div className="flip-card-inner">
      <div className="flip-card-front">
        <img src="#"/>
      </div>
      <div className="flip-card-back">
        <div className="flip-card-back-content">
          <h5>Text</h5>
          <span>Some text</span>
          <div className="sm">
            <a
              href="#"
            >
              FaGlobeAmericas
            </a>
            <br>
            <a
              href="#"
            >
              FaGlobeAmericas
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```